# How to upload two images (not array) with different names on Cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, cloudinary

I am working on a project using **NodeJs** and **Mongoose**. I have a customer schema with two different image attributes (1) `customer_profile_image` (2) `customer_logo` along with other customers' details. I want to upload both images using a POST API while adding a new customer **(not images array)** and I want one link for each image to be stored in the database after it is uploaded on Cloudinary. I have used Cloudinary before for uploading one image or array of images because it's easy to upload images with the same name, but in this case, I don't know how to upload two images with different names. What should I do? Does Cloudinary's upload function takes more than one parameter? and if it does, how to determine which image is currently uploading on the server and which link is for which image?
Below is the function I use to upload a single image on Cloudinary:

```
    app.post('/customer', upload.single('customer_profile_image'), async (request, response, next) => {
const path = request.file.path;
var uniqueFilename = new Date().toISOString();
var img = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
            path, {
            public_id: `blog/${uniqueFilename}`,
            tags: `blog`
        }, // directory and tags are optional
            async function (err, image) {
                if (err) return (err)
                fs.unlinkSync(path);
                // console.log(image);
                var customer = new Customer(request.body);
                customer.customer_profile_image= await image.secure_url
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to upload each image individually in its own upload call and specify the public id for that image. Cloudinary does not support uploading multiple images in one upload call. Furthermore, if you change your upload call to use the folder parameter instead of the public id, it will append a random string to the end. For instance, the Cloudinary upload all can look like this:

```
var customer = new Customer(request.body);
const path = request.file.path;
var customer_profile_image = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
            path, {
            folder: `blog/customer_profile_image`,
            // public id = blog/customer_profile_image/<randomly-generated-string>
            // e.g. blog/customer_profile_image/djqhfhwidhalwdi
            tags: `blog`
        }, // directory and tags are optional
            async function (err, image) {
                if (err) return (err)
                customer.customer_profile_image = image.secure_url
})
```

Similarly, you'll need to make a separate upload call for customer_logo

```
var customer_logo = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
            path, {
            folder: `blog/customer_logo`,
            // public id = blog/customer_logo/<randomly-generated-string>
            // e.g. blog/customer_logo/sdjoqnfhjahslq
            tags: `blog`
        }, // directory and tags are optional
            async function (err, image) {
                if (err) return (err)
                customer.customer_logo = image.secure_url
})
```

Comment: by saparate upload call did you mean saparate post api ? you're trying to say is i have to make two api's one which take customer_profile as params in upload.single function and other with customer logo as params.Forexample upload.single('customer_profile') & upload.single('customerLogo')  ??

Comment: how can i achieve this multiple image uploading in one post call ??

Comment: The two examples I included should be inside of your app.post as long as you pass two images inside of that post call.